# data frame aggregate and keep character column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have the data frame

```
     ID      type   Count   Out 

     1        A       1      11

     2        A       2      12

     2        B       5      10

     3        B       3      10

     3        B       5       7

     3        C       1       5
```

and the expected outcome is

```
    ID   type     Count(sum)    Out (sum)

     1     A        1             11  

     2     AB       7             22 

     3     BBC      9             22
```

I was trying aggregate function but the result table can be achieved without type column.

I was wondering if there is a way to keep characters as presented in the expected outcome table.

```
    ID      <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3)
    type    <- c("A","A","B", "B", "B","C")
    Count   <- c( 1,2,5,3,5,1)
    out     <- c(11,12,10,12,7,5)

    x       <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,Count,out))
    result  <- aggregate(x, list(x$ID), sum_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq in C# to achieve the operation you are describing. I've build the following Linq query to show how this is done. It maintains the order in the 2nd column because internally it's using an in-place algorithm. Mainly I've used the `GroupBy` Linq operator and the `String.Join` and `Sum` aggregate functions to solve the question.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        new { Id = 1, Type = "A", Count = 1, Out = 11 },
        new { Id = 2, Type = "A", Count = 2, Out = 12 },
        new { Id = 2, Type = "B", Count = 5, Out = 10 },
        new { Id = 3, Type = "B", Count = 3, Out = 10 },
        new { Id = 3, Type = "B", Count = 5, Out = 7 },
        new { Id = 3, Type = "C", Count = 1, Out = 5 },     
    };

    var result = data
        .GroupBy(d => d.Id)
        .Select(g => new 
        {
            Ids = g.Key, 
            Types = String.Join(String.Empty, g.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray()),
            Counts = g.Sum(d => d.Count),
            Outs = g.Sum(d => d.Out)
        })
        .ToList();

    result.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine($"{r.Ids} {r.Types} {r.Counts} {r.Outs}"));
}
```

This returns the following:

> 1 A 1 11
>
> 2 AB 7 22
>
> 3 BBC 9 22

Comment: Carlo, Thanks for the reply, there were formatting issues with the post. Actually, I do have data tables. I am using R for this